# Escape '+' sign in the request URL parameters

Tags: java, url, parameters, request

In our application some URLs are generated by appending the request params, some of these request params are used on those URLs for generating few labels, we are encoding these texts like below before generating the links:

```
title = URLEncoder.encode(match.getTitle(), "UTF-8");
```

When on the URL a '+' sign renders as blank, which is probably due to the fact that URL is considering the + as a space instead of a char, The URL is embedded in a static mail file which is not a part of application hence this dirty coding of appending the params to URL is done.
Please let me know if there is something that can be done to handle these kind of cases.

Thanks and Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: Can you give an example of input, output and desired output?

Comment: the URL generated is like "http://www.mytesturl.com?title=mp3+ipod+music" on the url it is displayed as a label mp3 ipod music

Comment: @vaibhav - What is the problem? Is it that some arbitrary mail program doesn't handle URLs correctly? The use of `+` for spaces is correct as per [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) - though replacing these with `%20` would also be correct.

Comment: I think Urls are Base64 encoded. So If you use such an encoder for your parameters you should be fine. There are quite some around (sun.misc.Base64Encoder or in Apache Commons Lang or Codec). In case its Java :)

Comment: thanks for the responses guys i would check and revert :)

Answer (score 0):

`+` should encode to %2B not space. But if it doesn't `match.getTitle().replaceAll("+", "%2B");`
and it should decode to + at the other end.